# how I take a fetchedObject in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8

I 'm trying to use this:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let task = tasks.fetchedObject[indexPath.row] as Task
    cell.textLabel?.text = task.n
}
```

but in my "let task" I receive this error:

"NSFetchedResultsController does not have a member named 'fetchedObject'"

what I can use instead of fetchedObject?

Comment: Try this.     let task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath.row) as Tasks

Comment: this return this error: viewController does not have a member named 'fetchedResultsController' but I do not yet implemented the delegate

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your fetchedObject you can set the cell title by looking up the key/value pair in the object, the attributeName should match exactly the attribute name listed in your .xcdatamodeld file .

```
let task = tasks.fetchedObject[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = task.valueForKey("attibuteName") as? String
```